# Conditional formatting changes number format - or does it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts, conditional-formatting

**The setup**

I have two conditional formatting rules that apply to a range of cells. The rules are:

`=R1C1="something"` -> have the number format be Number

`=R1C1<>"something"` -> have the number format be Percentage

It works: cell `R1C1` has data validation on it, so when I change the value, the number format on the range of cells changes accordingly.

**The problem**

I have a chart hooked up to the aforementioned range. **The vertical axis of this chart does not change with the number format on those cells.** It stays whatever the "hard-set" number format for those cells is (what I mean by "hard-set" is the format that you set using the controls for number format).

How can I have the chart change the number format of its vertical axis accordingly to the number format of its data range?

Comment: I believe you're stuck with the cell's underlying format-unless maybe you change it with VBA.  A possible workaround could use a different axis for the numbers and percentage-then having the series "turn on" or "turn off" based upon your variable.  Perhaps if you share a bit more a better, or different, option can be worked out.

Comment: Here's a VBA link to get you started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841205.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Using **VBA**, and assuming your formatting variable is in cell `A1` and your chart is named "Chart 1", here's the framework of code for a solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target = Range("A1") Then
    If [A1] = 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "00.00"

    ElseIf [A1] = 2 Then
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "$0"

    Else 
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

    End If

    Range("A1").Select

End If

End Sub
```